# Error Trying to get cell data value JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, getvalue

I am trying to get the value of the current cell, I am mapping an array list to a single column.

Here is my code:

```
TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            Integer rowIndex = cellData.getValue();
            return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(rangeArrayList.get(rowIndex));
        });

        tableView.getColumns().add(nameColumn);
```

Here is my error:

[image]

How would I be able to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this using a the `cellValueFactory` unless your item contains the row information, since there is no information about the row other than the value it contains in `TableColumn.CellDataFeatures`.

If you want to use the row number to retrieve the data, you can do this using a `cellFactory`, since the index is available to the `TableCell`:

```
public static <T> Callback<TableColumn<T, Void>, TableCell<T, Void>> cellFactory(final List<?> list) {
    return c -> new TableCell<T, Void>() {

        @Override
        public void updateIndex(int i) {
            super.updateIndex(i);
            setText(isEmpty() ? "" : Objects.toString(list.get(i), ""));
        }

    };
}
```

```
TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, Void> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
nameColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory(rangeArrayList));
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your effort, but I am not trying to display the row number, instead, I wish to populate data in this specific column.

Comment: @Milan Better now? Unsure why you're using `ObservableList<Sting>` as item type instead of one containing a property for the name though, since there seems to be no relation between cell content and item...

Comment: The reason why I am using ObservableList<String> as an item type, is because I am filling the rest of the columns with data from an arraylist. '